# Can't add cloud-archive:tools to repository

Tags: apt, maas

Trying to upgrade to MAAS 1.7, from 1.5, by updating apt-get repository; however, I am getting the following error:

```
$ sudo add-apt-repository cloud-archive:tools
 Ubuntu Cloud Archive for cloud-tools (JuJu and MAAS)
 More info: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/ServerTeam/CloudArchive
Press [ENTER] to continue or ctrl-c to cancel adding it

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/add-apt-repository", line 163, in <module>
    if not sp.add_source_from_shortcut(shortcut, options.enable_source):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/softwareproperties/SoftwareProperties.py", line 727, in add_source_from_shortcut
    (deb_line, file) = shortcut.expand(codename=self.distro.codename)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/softwareproperties/cloudarchive.py", line 98, in expand
    if codename not in (MAP[self.caname]['release'],
KeyError: 'release'
```

Tried the above on 2 14.04 boxes, with the same result. Any thoughts?
Cheers,

Answer (score 0):

From https://wiki.ubuntu.com/ServerTeam/CloudToolsArchive: "The Cloud Tools archive is only supported on Ubuntu 12.04"

I guess they haven't gotten to updating it to support 14.04.  The maas package in 14.10 is at version 1.7.0~beta8+bzr3272-0ubuntu1 -- note the "beta" word there, so as far as stable releases go, what is in 14.04 is the latest one.

Answer (score 0):

Try https://launchpad.net/~maas-maintainers/+archive/ubuntu/stable for the current stable version of MAAS.